# Android Espresso not synchronized with Rx Completable

Tags: android, rx-java, android-espresso

I have an issue with Espresso not waiting for Completable to finish, so my UI test is Failing

```
apiDataSource.getData()
             .flatMap { data ->
                    cacheDataSource.saveData(data)
                    .andThen(Observable.just(cacheDataSource.getData()))
```

is there a way to hold the Espresso thread until having the `cacheDataSource.saveData(data)` complete?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that you call `cacheDataSource.getData()` right when you assemble the save sequence inside `flatMap`. From the documentation of [`just`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/3.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/rxjava3/core/Observable.html#just-T-):

> Note that the item is taken and re-emitted as is and not computed by any means by just. Use fromCallable(Callable) to generate a single item on demand (when Observers subscribe to it).

```kotlin
apiDataSource.getData()
         .flatMap { data ->
                cacheDataSource.saveData(data)
                .andThen(Observable.fromCallable { cacheDataSource.getData() })
         }
```